# Google Slides - how to automatically run a google add-on and apply custom layout?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm currently working on the implementation of the AppScript add-on for Google Slides.
I want my add-on to start when the user opens a new presentation.
I want the add-on to change the layout of all slides, maybe there is a way to import custom layout from file?
Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the on open (simple or installabl) trigger to add a menu and to do some other tasks that doesn't require user authorization but not to change the layout of all slides as something like that requires authorization. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers